# How to replace a regex pattern with a regex pattern?

Tags: php, regex, csv, match

I'm feeling very silly for not being able to figure this one out, but I just cant figure it. I need to replace a regex string with a pattern, I found two examples of doing it, but they honestly left me more confused than ever.

This is my current attempt:

```
$string = '26 14:46:54",,"2011-08-26 14:47:02",8,0,"BUSY","DOCUMENTATION","1314370014.18","","","61399130249","7466455647","from-internal","""Oh Snap"" <61399130249>","SIP/1037-00000014","SIP/CL-00000015","Dial","SIP/CL/61436523277,45","2011-08-26 14:47:06","2011-08-26 14:47:15","2011-08-26 ';
$pattern = '["SIP/CL/\d*?,\d*?",]';
$replacement = '"SIP/CL/\1|\2",';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
print($string);
```

But that just replaces the `\1` and `\2` with blanks. So obviously I'm not getting the entire concept.

What I'm wanting at the end is to change:

```
this: "SIP/CL/61436523277,45"
to: "SIP/CL/61436523277|45"
```

That comma in a poorly formatted CSV throws off some of my other scripts.

Comment: It doesn't seem poorly formatted, as it is between quotes... You DO use [`fgetcsv`](http://www.php.net/fgetcsv) for this, are you not? Or [`str_getcsv`](http://www.php.net/str_getcsv) if it is a string.

Comment: I wasn't, but i am now. I needed to learn this form of regex replacement anyway. So killed two birds with one stone :). I was aware of fgetcsv, but it didn't suit my purposes (its a 1.8GB+ csv...., cant load it all in mem), but str_getcsv worked well! :)

Comment: OK, for future reference: `fgetcsv` doesn't read a total file into memory either, just line by line ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing braces, the pattern should look like this:

```
$pattern = '["SIP/CL/(\d*),(\d*)",]';
```

Comment: That was it? I feel like such a foo'. Thank you so much :) That worked perfectly.

Comment: you have changed the meaning of the non-gready operator by having outside the bracket. It shoud be (\d+?)

Comment: @user1130968 marking the most useful answer as answer is best way of saying thanks here .) (so does FAQ say)

Comment: @meouw you're right, I didn't notice that I just added braces I wouldn't use it at all

Comment: The final looked like
    $pattern = '["SIP/CL/(\d*),(\d*)",]';
    $replacement = '"SIP/CL/\1|\2,"';

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this:

```
$pattern = '["SIP/CL/(\d+),(\d+)",]';
```

The parens - `()` - capture the match inside, allowing you to reference it in your replacement pattern.

You could also simplify the replacement pattern by expanding the captures in the match pattern:

```
$pattern = '[("SIP/CL/\d+),(\d+",)]';   
$replacement = '\1|\2';
```

Answer (score 2):

The backreferences `\1` and `\2` in your `$replacement` are meant to refer to *captured groups* in `$pattern`. Captured groups are saved by placing brackets around them `()`.

Try (I changed your regex delimiters `[]` to `!` pending an answer from comments below):

```
$pattern = '!"SIP/CL/(\d*?),(\d*?)",!';
$replacement = '"SIP/CL/\1|\2",';
```

Also note that since you have a trailing comma on your `$pattern`, if your `$string` ended in `"SIP/CL/61436523277,45"` that would not be converted. I'd recommend removing that trailing comma.

Also your current regex will convert `"SIP/CL/,"` to `"SIP/CL/|"`. If that is not your intent, change the `*` after the `\d` (ie 0 or more matches) to a `+` (one or more matches).

Comment: [ and ] will be taken as delimeters in this case, not a character class

Comment: would not pattern 1 be SIP/CL/{numbershere} So should you want `'"SIP/CL/(\d*?),(\d*?)",'` or else your first reference is funny.  As in your replacement would be `SIP/CL/SIP/CL/numbershere|numbersagain`

Comment: @meouw, I forgot about that, cheers. but then shouldn't it be `[` and `[` or `]` and `]` but not `[` and `]`?

Comment: PHP, like Perl, recognizes correctly-paired brackets as delimiters, so `[]`, `()`, `{}` and `<>` all work.  I think it's a bad idea to use them in PHP though; it's confusing enough that, unlike in Perl, you have to use regex delimiters *in addition to* quotes.  At the least, anyone looking at your code is going to wonder if **you** understand why it's valid. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
$string = '26 14:46:54",,"2011-08-26 14:47:02",8,0,"BUSY","DOCUMENTATION","1314370014.18","","","61399130249","7466455647","from-internal","""Oh Snap"" <61399130249>","SIP/1037-00000014","SIP/CL-00000015","Dial","SIP/CL/61436523277,45","2011-08-26 14:47:06","2011-08-26 14:47:15","2011-08-26 ';
$pattern = '/SIP\/CL\/([0-9]+),([0-9]+)/';
$replacement = 'SIP/CL/\1|\2';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
print($string);
```