# How to substitute a regex with another regex in a string

Tags: python, regex

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903547/how-to-replace-a-regex-pattern-with-a-regex-pattern) showed how to **replace** a regex with another regex like this

```
$string = '"SIP/1037-00000014","SIP/CL-00000015","Dial","SIP/CL/61436523277,45"';
$$pattern = '["SIP/CL/(\d*),(\d*)",]';
$replacement = '"SIP/CL/\1|\2",';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
print($string);
```

However, I couldn't adapt that pattern to solve my case where I want to remove the full stop that lies between 2 words but not between a word and a number:

```
text = 'this . is bad. Not . 820'
regex1 = r'(\w+)(\s\.\s)(\D+)'
regex2 = r'(\w+)(\s)(\D+)'
re.sub(regex1, regex2, text)

# Desired outcome:
'this is bad. Not . 820'
```

Basically I like to remove the `.` between the two alphabet words. Could someone please help me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These expressions might be close to what you might have in mind:

```
\s[.](?=\s\D)
```

or

```
(?<=\s)[.](?=\s\D)
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"\s[.](?=\s\D)"
test_str = "this . is bad. Not . 820"
print(re.sub(regex, "", test_str))
```

#### Output

```
this is bad. Not . 820
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DzbKRu/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/DzbKRu/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks, Emma. Your solution is almost perfect. However, I like to obtain this outcome `this is bad. Not . 820` where the full stop remains between **Not** and **820**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't really take PHP and apply it directly to Python, for obvious reasons.

Secondly, it always helps to specify which version of Python you're using as APIs change. Luckily in this instance, the API of `re.sub` has remained the same between Python 2.x and Python 3.

Onto your issue.

The second argument to `re.sub` is either a string  or a function. If you pass in `regex2` it'll just replace `regex1` with the string contents of `regex2`, it won't apply `regex2` as a regex.

If you want to use groups derived from the first regex (similar to your example, which is using \1 and \2 to extract the first and second matching group from the first regex), then you'd want to [use a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), which takes a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) as its sole argument, which you could then use to extract matching groups  and return them as part of the replacement string.

Comment: Thanks, Liam. I didn't know the sample code I relied on was PHP. I did know that the second argument of `re.sub` must be string or callable. But the sample code (which I thought was Python) showed it could be done thus my question.